# Render React Element within Array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, components

I have an array of items, which are defined by a string and an icon component:

```
type MyItem = {
  Title: string;
  Icon: React.ElementType;
};

export const MyItems: MyItem[] = [
  { Title: "Inbox", Icon: InboxIcon },
  { Title: "Users", Icon: UserIcon },
  { Title: "Settings", Icon: SettingsIcon },
];
```

Now I want to display them within a component:

```
<>
    {MyItems.map((item, index) => (
      <h1>item.Title</h1>
      // render icon component here: item.Icon
    ))}
</>
```

How can I render the icon component (without changing the array structure)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here that your icons are essentially React Components. If so then you can try out the code below:

```
<>
    {MyItems.map((item, index) => (
      <>
      <h1>item.Title</h1>
      {item.Icon}
      </>
    ))}
</>
```

Comment: https://mui.com/components/material-icons/

Those are my icons.

Comment: Already tried that and tried it again. I do get a blank screen if I put it whtin { }.

Comment: Have you tried removing `(` after `=>`? I noticed it now that it's not needed.  Try removing that bracket open and a `) ` on the 7th line.

Comment: As for your icons in the `MyItems` array, use `<InboxIcon />`,  `<UserIcon />` and `<SettingsIcon />` for respective item.

Comment: Thanks that did work. I used React.ReactElement instead of React.ElementType and for the Array I used <InboxIcon />, <UserIcon /> and <SettingsIcon />.